# Jetson TX2 vs small form factor PC for autonomous robots

Tags: mobile-robot, autonomous-car

What are the advantages and disadvantages for each?

I can build a small form factor PC with a GTX 1050 which will easily out perform a jetson for the same price.

When and where are each more appropriate to use? What are the advantages of each?

Comment: what do you mean by `out perform`?

Comment: computational power, you get x3 the cuda core on a gtx 1050

Comment: you are talking about use in a battery powered device ... why are you not mentioning power requirement in your definition of `out perform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Jetson TX2 is about 15 Watts at full load and can run from 9v-15v.

The PC with GTX 1050 will be above 300 Watts and likely require both 5v and 12v supplies with little wiggle room in those numbers.

A mobile robot would need to be quite big to carry the batteries for the PC+GPU This would also be larger in physical size.

The Jetson TX2 is smaller, lighter and with the lower power requirements can have a smaller battery.